# pandas apply() with and without lambda

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

What is the rule/process when a function is called with pandas `apply()` through lambda vs. not? Examples below. Without lambda apparently, the entire series ( df[column name] ) is passed to the "test" function which throws an error trying to do a boolean operation on a series.

If the same function is called via lambda it works. Iteration over each row with each passed as "x" and the df[ column name ] returns a single value for that column in the current row.

It's like lambda is removing a dimension. Anyone have an explanation or point to the specific doc on this?  Thanks.

**Example 1 with lambda, works OK**

```
print("probPredDF columns:", probPredDF.columns)

def test( x, y):
    if x==y:
        r = 'equal'
    else:
        r = 'not equal'
    return r    

probPredDF.apply( lambda x: test( x['yTest'], x[ 'yPred']), axis=1 ).head()
```

**Example 1 output**

```
probPredDF columns: Index([0, 1, 'yPred', 'yTest'], dtype='object')

Out[215]:
0    equal
1    equal
2    equal
3    equal
4    equal
dtype: object
```

**Example 2 without lambda, throws boolean operation on series error**

```
print("probPredDF columns:", probPredDF.columns)

def test( x, y):
    if x==y:
        r = 'equal'
    else:
        r = 'not equal'
    return r    

probPredDF.apply( test( probPredDF['yTest'], probPredDF[ 'yPred']), axis=1 ).head()
```

**Example 2 output**

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing magic about a `lambda`.  They are functions in one parameter, that can be defined inline, and do not have a name.  You can use a function where a lambda is expected, but the function will need to also take one parameter. You need to do something like...

**Define it as:**

```
def wrapper(x):
    return test(x['yTest'], x['yPred'])
```

**Use it as:**

```
probPredDF.apply(wrapper, axis=1)
```

Comment: Plus One because this is a great answer and all... But I have to disagree!  The **IS** something magic about a `lambda`.

Comment: Well at many levels I still find python magical, as it makes me absurdly productive as a programmer.  But I don't think lambda contains any more magic than comprehensions, and certainly less magic than decorators...  :-)

Comment: Touche... no arguments here

Comment: What a great idea. I have been passing functions to apply for ages and never thought to put them in a wrapper. Makes the call so much clearer.