# How to assign an element in tuple when using "apply" method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

Let say I have the following function which returns a tuple:

```
def return_tuple(x):
    if x in [1,'1','one']: 
        return (1, 'one')
    else:
        return (2, 'two')
```

If I use apply method, this would returns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]})
df['test'] = df['col1'].apply(return_tuple)

>>
    col1    test
0   1   (1, one)
1   2   (2, two)
2   one (1, one)
```

But I would like something like this:

```
df['test_1'] = df['col1'].apply(return_tuple)??? # get 0-index in tuple
df['test_2'] = df['col1'].apply(return_tuple)??? # get 1 index in tuple

>>
    col1    test_1    test_2
0   1         1        one
1   2         2        two
2   one       1        one
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere inbetween Alexander's and razdi's answers, using `zip` and tuple unpacking:

```
import pandas as pd

def return_tuple(x):
    if x in [1, '1', 'one']:
        return 1, 'one'
    else:
        return 2, 'two'

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3]})

df_1['test_1'], df_1['test_2'] = zip(*df_1['col1'].apply(return_tuple))
```

Comment: 1. How are you everywhere? :p 2. Nice!

Comment: I could ask you the same thing ;)

Comment: Cool use of the unpack operator :p

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it in a single step:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]})

def return_tuple(x):
    if x['col1'] in [1,'1','one']: 
        return pd.Series([1, 'one'])
    else:
        return pd.Series([2, 'two'])

df[['test_1', 'test_2']] = df.apply(return_tuple, axis=1)
```

Comment: That does make the function far less versatile though, so it depends on whether or not it is used elsewhere.

Comment: Fair point. This could be much less flexible depending on the use case. But based on the example shown, I think this response could wok well too.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

def return_tuple(x):
    if x in [1, '1', 'one']:
        return 1, 'one'
    else:
        return 2, 'two'


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3]})

df_1['test_1'] = df_1['col1'].apply(lambda item: return_tuple(item)[0])
df_1['test_2'] = df_1['col1'].apply(lambda item: return_tuple(item)[1])

print(df_1)
```

It's as simple as that!

For more on lambda functions, you can see https://realpython.com/python-lambda/. There are a few relevant question on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43810094/11301900).

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this one-liner without altering your existing function:

```
df[['test_1','test_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(return_tuple).tolist(),index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of modification, here is the result:

```
df[['test1', 'test2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(return_tuple).tolist(), index=df.index)
df
```

Here df join is used

Comment: @chun-yin-to just copy-paste to check

Comment: this is a copy paste of my earlier answer

Comment: @DerekEden if they r identical, it does not mean copy paste. do be over confident. I can show u screeshot of my jupyter notebook

Comment: just saying...check answers before posting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can expand it to do what you want:

```
def return_tuple(x):
    if x in [1,'1','one']: 
        return (1, 'one')
    else:
        return (2, 'two')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]})
df['test'] = df['col1'].apply(return_tuple)


 df[['test','test2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['test'].to_list(), index=df.index)


Out[32]: 
   col1  test test2
0     1     1   one
1     2     2   two
2     3     2   two
```